# printf function string printout argument usage

Tags: c

I'm currently encountering this problem. I wanted to print out the `#` as I defined in the code block below, thing is when I pass the `printf` argument as `printf("%*s\n", x, BORDER)`, it prints out all the `#` I defined at the beginning. However, when I write it as `printf("%.*s\n", x, BORDER)` then it prints out just as many `#` as I wanted. Can someone tell me what's the difference that triggered this problem? I know width and precision stand an important role when it comes to float number printout, but this is string print out...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BORDER "############################################"

int main(void) {
    char word[26];
    int x;

    scanf("%25s", word);
    x = strlen(word) + 2;
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    printf("%*s\n", x, BORDER);
    printf("#%s#\n", word);    
    printf("%*s\n", x, BORDER);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to read the man page? It is quite involved. The man pages should always be your first reference.

Comment: The difference between specified *width* and specified *precision* for strings. See the [documentation for **`printf`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), and read it carefully. When using `s`, *"Precision specifies the maximum number of bytes to be written."*

Comment: Yes read the man page. It tells you in specific detail: "...or the maximum number of characters to be printed from a string for s and S conversions"

Answer (score 2):

Here is the difference between the two syntaxes:

- The optional *field width* passed with `%*s` specifies the minimum width to print for the string.  If the string is shorter, extra spaces will be printed before the string.
- The optional *precision* passed with `%.*s` specifies to maximum number of characters to print from the string argument.

In your case, you want to limit the number of characters to print from the `BORDER` string, so you should use the `%.*s` format:

```
printf("%.*s\n", x, BORDER);
```

Note however that this approach is not generic as you must keep to definition of `BORDER` in sync with the array size.

Here is a different approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char word[26];

    if (scanf("%25s", word) == 1) {
        int x = strlen(word) + 2;
        char border[x + 2];

        memset(border, '#', x);
        border[x] = '\0';

        printf("x = %d\n", x);
        printf("%s\n#%s#\n%s\n", border, x, border);
    }    
    return 0;
}
```